# Kiom da renkontiĝoj uzas la monunuon "Stelo" ĉiujare?

Tags: culture

Laŭ tiu [vikipedia artikolo](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stelo_(monunuo)), Stelo-monunuo ankoraŭ estas uzata. Ĝi estas el plasto kaj iu grupo nomita "Stelaro" zorgas pri ĝi. Mi volas havi ideon pri kiom ofte ĝi estas uzata.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Steloj estas ĉiujare uzataj dum KKPS en Nederlando (kkps.esperanto-jongeren.nl) kaj IJF en Italujo (iej.esperanto.it/ijf/). Krome fojfoje dum JES aŭ IJK, kiam la loka teamo estas bonvena al ili, kaj verŝajne ankaŭ dum FESTO en Francujo kiam ĝi denove okazos.